# Firefox is saving but not using saved login data

Tags: security, firefox, authentication, passwords

I'm using this webmailer to check my private email:

https://webmailer.hosteurope.de/login.php

using FireFox as browser on several different computer systems.

However I have the problem with one of my computers:

Firefox IS saving the login data (login+password) but the next time I'm accessing the webmailer page this data is not used.
That means on this system I have to type my username+password everytime I
want to check my mails which is quite annoying.

Of course I've already tried the usual hints (Google was my friend) but the problem IS NOT that data is not saved! The problem is that saved login data is not used!

Any hints what my cause this problem?

ps: The misbehaving system is new and was configured with a preinstalled :-\ Win10 - all other systems are Win7. But I cannot imagine that this might be causing this behavior!? Firefox was manually installed by me on all systems. So no special settings that I applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to `Preferences -> Security -> Saved Logins...` and check whether the correct domain name is stored. It could be that you saved the login information after you input them wrong. Sometimes when you input wrong username/password you get redirected to a separate page that informs you that you input the wrong credentials. This page sometimes has a login form. If you save the credentials when you are on that page they may only be filled on that page and not the main login page. For example, if you input wrong credentials on `somedomain.com` and get redirected to `somedomain.com/wrong_password` and save the credentials there, Firefox might only fill the form on the later page.

If this fails, try refreshing Firefox. Be careful to backup important data first. Usually they are restored automatically, but sometimes it fails. Instructions here: https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Procedures-to-diagnose-and-fix/Refresh-Firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings/ta-p/23405

If everything fails, you can report it to Firefox at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: I already removed all saved logins (there were not many as it's a fresh installation) and re-did the whole procedure without success. Website/Address, username and password are stored correctly but neither the username nor the password is filled in. I will try to refresh and report the result.

Comment: Refreshing Firefox did not help. I deleted all saved logins and repeated the procedure without success. Login is saved but the data is still not filled in when  I open the login page again.

Comment: There used to be an HTML option where Firefox would not save login information of webpages that had it, but since Firefox 38 it seems that it's not respected any longer. Sounds more like a bug to me. Please report it at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ Also before reporting please check that all the preferences (especially privacy and security tabs) are the same as in your other computers. I know that some add-ons modify them.

Comment: Another thing you can try is create a Firefox account on a computer that it's working, and sync all your data between the two computers. It is not guaranteed that it will work, but probably worth trying. If you reinstall Firefox on the computer that is not working, even better probably.

Comment: Syncing with my Firefox account cured the problem.